# Nested hidden tags scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

First things first, very new to python and web scraping.

I have a page that needs to be scraped. I was looking at a lot of sources and wasn't able to figure out the scraping of nested hidden tags. The page requires a login and being able to grab the visible data, which my code successfully executes. However, when it comes to scraping the nested elements within a `div` tag, it doesn't find anything.

**HTML** (before onClick() event)

```
<div id="topMenu" style="width: 1920px; position: relative; top: 46px;" onclick="menu(event);" oncontextmenu="javascript:if(!event.ctrlKey){return RightClickPopUp(event);}">
   <span id="3" class="cSub" lcid="63" lccl="Item" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; top: 20px;"> 
        <span id="1" menuname="Cancel" parentid="63" class="Menu01" showmenu="010">Cancel</span>
   </span>

   <span id="3" class="cSub" lcid="63" lccl="Item" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; top: 20px;"> 
        <span id="1" menuname="Cancel" parentid="63" class="Menu01" showmenu="010">Cancel</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

After I click on the `div` (consists of multiple buttons), the first `span` tag becomes visible and then jumps into its appropriate nested `span` tag. My problem is to access the text in the innermost `span`.

**HTML** (After onClick() event)

```
<div id="topMenu" style="width: 1920px; position: relative; top: 46px;" onclick="menu(event);" oncontextmenu="javascript:if(!event.ctrlKey){return RightClickPopUp(event);}">
     <span id="3" class="cSub" lcid="63" lccl="Item" style="visibility: visible; display: inline; top: 20px;"> 
          <span id="1" menuname="Cancel" parentid="63" class="Menu01" showmenu="010">Cancel</span>
     </span>

      <span id="3" class="cSub" lcid="63" lccl="Item" style="visibility: visible; display: inline; top: 20px;"> 
          <span id="1" menuname="Cancel" parentid="63" class="Menu01" showmenu="010">Cancel</span>
      </span>
</div>
```

**Python Code**

```
import mechanize 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()

br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("LOGIN_URL")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['USER'] = 'un'
br.form['PASSWORD'] = 'pwd'
br.submit()

check = br.response().read()
print(check) //login success 

my_url = br.open("URL_I_NEED_TO_SCRAPE").read()
page_soup = soup(my_url, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.find("div",{"id":"topMenu"})
```

**This code helps me get the `div`, but nothing inside it. Is there a way to get the `spans` that are currently hidden inside this `div`?**

Comment: have you tried simply items = soup.select("#topMenu [id='1']") I guess partly depends whether you need to have an actual on the page action to enable selection of these.

Comment: Its empty. This is what I get: [ ]

Comment: you may need something like selenium where you can interact with the page.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The text inside the innermost span @JackFleeting

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to extract inner hidden elements like span,  src, and alt tag.

```
containers = page_soup.find("div",{"id":"topMenu"})
top_span=containers.find_all('span',class_='cSub')
print(len(top_span)
#len of spans is two
inner_span=top_span[0].find('span')
inner_span_text=inner_span.text
class_inside_inner_span=inner_span['class']
```

for more details of web scraping follow my this post: "https://github.com/rajat4665/web-scraping-with-python"

Comment: When I print the length for this, it outputs 0. It's still somehow not getting the span

Comment: Hi caitlin, i exactly don't know why are you getting len of span zero but as far i know you might choosen wrong class name.

Comment: I have figured out the solution using selenium